# How to let googlebot access pages behind a login

Tags: authentication

Have searched the net and here too, but still looking for a solid answer to allowing Googlebot to access pages behind my login.

Is there a secure way to do this?

I have added a login allow through Adsense, but wish to go further than just permitting pages that contain Adsense content.

I receive report that 238 pages have access denied errors.

Would appreciate some help here.

Kind Regards Chris

Comment: What is your web server and configuration?

Answer (score 0):

How about checking ip (whether it starts with 66.249.*) and user-agent (Googlebot) and serve authorized pages if both of the situations matches ?